# Go templates iterate over multiple arrays together

Tags: html, templates, go

I've read through a lot of posts here related to Go templates but I can't find what I'm looking for.

I have these 2 structs, which I cannot change as they are used elsewhere in this project I am helping with:

```
type Schedule struct {
    Description   string
    ControlNights int
    PlayNights    int
    StartDay      int
    Combos        []Combo
}

type Combo struct {
    From    time.Time
    Every   int
    Until   time.Time
    Sounds  []string
    Volumes []int
    Waits   []int
}
```

And I need to display this data on an html page.  So I need to iterate over each Combo. Which I can do, but I need to have the Sounds, Volumes and Waits on rows together i.e. Sound x volume y wait z.  Where x,y and z are the values in the Sounds, Volumes and Waits arrays.  These arrays can be of any length >= 1 but they will all have the same length.

I want it to look like this:

[image]

I have tried this:

```
            {{range .Schedule.Combos}}
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card mt-2 ml-2">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">
                                    <strong>Timing</strong>
                                </h5>
                                <h5 class="card-text">
                                    Play every {{.Every}} mins
                                </h5>
                                <h5 class="card-text">
                                    From time {{TimeOfDayToString .From}}
                                </h5>
                                <h5 class="card-text">
                                    Until {{TimeOfDayToString .Until}}
                                </h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card mt-2">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">
                                    <strong>Sounds</strong>
                                </h5>
                                {{range .Sounds}}
                                    <h5 class="card-text">
                                        Sound {{.}}
                                    </h5>
                                {{end}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And that allows me to range over the sounds, but I need to range over the volumes and waits (times to wait until playing next sound) as well, at the same time somehow...

I guess what I could do is make a different Combo struct and pass that to my html template, but I was hoping to avoid that if there's a way to do it with the structs as they are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are *sure* that those three arrays have the same number of elements, then you can do this:

```
{{ $volumes := .Volumes }}
{{ $waits := .Waits }}
{{range $index,$sound := .Sounds }}

Print Sounds[i] like this: {{$sound}}

Print volumes[i] like this: {{index $volumes $index}}

Print waits[i] like this: {{index $waits $index}}

{{end}}
```

This should give you the idea.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I don't understand this line: {{range $index,$sound := .Sounds }}  What is happening there? Is $index built in?

Comment: `{{range $index, $sound := .Sounds }}` is the same as `for index, sound := range Sounds`. The `:=` defines variables `$index` and `$sound`. When you define variables in a template, you use the `$` prefix, otherwise they are interpreted as functions. Read the templates doc https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/

Comment: Ok, I thought that might be what it was.  Freakin hard to work all this out from the documentation mate.  Hence all the queries here on StackOverflow.  Didn't know you could structure the for loop like that.