# How to range over a struct of slice of type structs in go templates

Tags: go

I have a struct of slice of type struct:

```
type Tplpass struct {
    Forums    []Forum
    LastTopic []Topic
}
err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", Tplpass{Forums: forums, LastTopic:last_topic})
```

I want them to range simultaneously like this:

```
Forums[1]
    LastTopic[1]
Forums[2]
    LastTopic[2]
Forums[3]
    LastTopic[3]
...
```

I've tried to use this code:

```
{{ $forums := .Forums }}
{{ $topic := .LastTopic }}
{{range $Forums := $forums}}
<tr>
    <td>Immage</td>           
    <td><a href="{{.Id}}">{{.Name}}</a> <br>{{.Descr}}</td>
    
    {{range $LastTopic := $topic}}
    <td>236 <br> topic</td>
    <td>1000 <br>message</td>
    <td>{{.Date}} <br> in <a href="/showtopic?id={{.Topic_id}}">Here i need to access {{.Title}} of $forums</a> <br> di <a href="/profile?id=">{{.Author}}</a></td>
    
</tr>
{{end}}    {{end}}
```

But it print like this:

```
Forums[1]
    LastTopic[1]
    LastTopic[2]
    LastTopic[3]
    ...
Forums[2]
    LastTopic[1]
    LastTopic[2]
    LastTopic[3]
    ...
Forums[3]
    LastTopic[1]
    LastTopic[2]
    LastTopic[3]
    ...
...
```

And I need to access {{.Title}} of $forums while ranging $topic.
How should I properly access the data?

Comment: Does [Go templates iterate over multiple arrays together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58496083/5728991) answer your question?

Comment: @Cerise Limón Can you write an example with my data structure, I'm really confused with the answer you posted. Thanks

Comment: `{{range $index, $Forums := $forums}} {{$LastTopic := index $topic $index}} Forums[i].Title is {{$Forums.Title}} LastTopic[i].Topic_id is {{$LastTopic.Topic_id}} {{end}}`

Comment: @Cerise Limón panic: template: index.html:38: undefined variable "$forums"

Comment: The snippet assumes your existing definition of the variable. To apply linked answer to your question, add index variable to the range. Use index function to get corresponding last topic for a forum. https://go.dev/play/p/vAgkoMIWvW-